# Insert into as select from array and struct table in HIVE

Tags: arrays, struct, hive, ddl

I'm having a hard time to insert structured arrays into a table as select from another one:

this is my create table:

```
create table temp4
(
nome_1 string
,array_nm1 array<struct<nome1:string, chave1:string, valor1:string, record1:struct<nome4:string>>>
,array_nm2 struct<nome2:string, chave2:string, valor2:string>
);
```

then I insert data into:

```
INSERT INTO temp4 select 
'artur',
ARRAY(NAMED_STRUCT('nome1','artur','chave1','a1','valor1','23', 'record1', NAMED_STRUCT('nome4','lucas'))) as array_nm1,
NAMED_STRUCT('nome2','seidi','chave2','s1','valor2','08') as array_nm2
FROM (select '1' ) t;
```

This works pretty fine. So I create another table and tried to input data from 'temp4'
But i cannot manage to insert from temp4 to another complex table. Like:

```
create table temp5
(
name_1 string
,array_nm3 array<struct<name1:string,key1:string,value1:string,rec1:struct<name4:string>>>
,array_nm4 struct<name2:string,key2:string,value2:string>
);
```

I've tried something like this:

```
INSERT into temp5
select
name_1 as name_1,
array(named_struct(name1,nome1,key1,chave1, value1,valor1, rec1, named_struct(name4, nome4))) as array_nm3,
named_struct(name2,nome2,key2,chave2, value2, valor2) as array_nm4
from temp4
```

But didn't succeed.
Also tried array_nm1.nome1 as array_nm3.name1 but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the insert query as below. Make the keys as string values in the named_struct. Also named_struct key should match the same as the keys defined in temp5 DDL.

```
INSERT into temp5
select
 name_1 as name_1,
 array(named_struct('name1',nome1,'key1',chave1, 'value1',valor1, 'rec1',named_struct('name4', nome4))) as array_nm3,
 named_struct('name2',nome2,'key2',chave2, 'value2', valor2) as array_nm4
 
from temp4
```

Comment: Interesting this worked for me. Have you tried giving the key name as 'name1' instead of name1 ?

Comment: hive>
    > INSERT into temp5
    > select
    > nome_1 as name_1,
    > array(named_struct('name1',nome1,'key1',chave1, 'value1',valor1, 'rec1',named_struct('name4', nome4))) as array_nm3,
    > named_struct('name2',nome2,'key2',chave2, 'value2', valor2) as array_nm4
    > from temp4
    > ;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 4:27 Invalid table alias or column reference 'nome1': (possible column names are: nome_1, array_nm1, array_nm2)
hive>

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
INSERT into temp5
select
nome_1 as name_1,
array(named_struct('name1',tb.array_nm1[0].nome1,'key1',tb.array_nm1[0].chave1, 'value1',tb.array_nm1[0].valor1, 'rec1',named_struct('name4', tb.array_nm1[0].record1.nome4))) as array_nm3,
named_struct('name2',tb.array_nm2.nome2,'key2',tb.array_nm2.chave2, 'value2', tb.array_nm2.valor2) as array_nm4
from temp4 as tb
```